# Number theory, Algebra and Precalculus book

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I need to start applying to competitive exams from next year and want to generally cover mathematics up to Under-graduate level as soon as possible to study for a different field

To have a strong base I searched a lot for books and finally came to Art of Problem Solving
I have three books in mind:

Pre calculus AOSP, Introduction to number theory AOSP and Intermediate Algebra AOSP

I will be only able to do two of these books so it would be really helpful if you could recommend any other books and help me choose between these

I am a new member and a beginner who knows the contents from Introduction to Algebra + Some basic calculus except Logarithms

I look forward to study advanced mathematics like Calculus so would be helpful if you recommend any book for that

Thank you

Comment: To reach graduate level you will need a lot more than 2 books.

Comment: Based on the books that Mikul mentioned, I don't think he really means graduate level. I'm guessing Mikul's looking for establishing a general mathematics base to study another subject of interest.

Mikul, if you're looking to do math competitions, then studying on your own may be difficult. Art of Problem Solving has many excellent online classes for motivated students just like you, and you should take a few of their classes first and gain enough mathematical maturity before deciding what to study on your own.

Comment: Note: Intermediate Algebra can be regarded as a prerequisite to Precalculus, although there is a lot of overlap. That said, Precalculus is the critical base for many later subjects, so don't rush it. If you take the time to truly _master_ Precalculus, it will pay you back many times over for the extra time spent.

Comment: Thank you so much and yes I didn't mean Graduate level it was an over-exaggeration I guess

Comment: I was looking for more cost efficiency @Albert and AOPS classes are costly

Comment: @quasi I will do the intermediate algebra and the pre-calculus then and leave Number theory because I guess it's similar